# if condition inside ajaxcomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
//listen to ajax start event
    $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
      $('.loaderr').fadeIn();
    });

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
          $('.loaderr').fadeOut();

          if($('.ajax_add_to_cart_button').data('clicked')) {
                 $('#miniLeftCart').delay(400).animate({ 'zoom': 1.5 }, 350)
                 $('#miniLeftCart').delay(500).animate({ 'zoom': 1 }, 200)
                 return false;
          } else {
                //run function2
          }
        });
```

I have a link when clicked on it ajax is called. And Since I have more AJAX calls on my website, I want this

```
$('#miniLeftCart').delay(400).animate({ 'zoom': 1.5 }, 350)
 $('#miniLeftCart').delay(500).animate({ 'zoom': 1 }, 200)
```

to start only when I click on **ajax_add_to_cart_button**

How can I make it?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just assigning a click event to the desired button?

Comment: You opened my eyes! There is no reason :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To echo my comment, just assign a click event to the desired button:

```
$( ".ajax_add_to_cart_button" ).click(function() {
    $('#miniLeftCart').delay(400).animate({ 'zoom': 1.5 }, 350);
    $('#miniLeftCart').delay(500).animate({ 'zoom': 1 }, 200);
});
```